# What is the current state-of-the-art video classification technique?

Tags: classification, cnn, lstm

For a project I am aiming to automise the detection of goals in foosball (a.k.a. 'table football') matches. To do so I now track the ball in every frame using the openCV library in Python.

To determine if a ball has been shot into the goal and should count as a point I want to train a neural network on videos that include goals and non-goals. When the ball is not found for a number of frames, I want the algorithm to put the video through a neural network to determine if it disappeared because a team scored.

I've been doing some research on video classification techniques but cannot really determine which one works best on classifying videos right now.

Currently I am considering first training a CNN on single frames out of the videos, and then gathering the convolutional features for the videos by feeding them through the network (with classification layer and fully-connected layers popped off), after which the convolutional features are put through an LSTM classification network sequentially for each video.

Is this the best way to go about such a problem, or are there better techniques available?

Comment: Your question title and body do not match. Could you please make it clear whether you want to know about state of the art video classification techniques (which you would then want to experiment with to find out how they apply), or want to discuss approaches to detecting scored goals in foosball. There's a good chance that the two do not overlap much because of the specifics in your foosball case, so you are best off asking about one or the other.

Comment: Technically a video classifier would take a video as input and return its class. That *could* be whether a goal is scored or not. But it might be whether the video was happy or sad or some another emotion, whether it showed a crime being committed, etc etc. It is a very broad subject, which is why you may not want to search for a "best video classifier". Specifically in foosball, the action is very fast, and the objects in frame very predicable. Worth adding whether you have rigged up a table with fixed camera and lighting, or want to enable use of mobile phone cameras etc.